# What is the name of the travel show that exposes how travelers are conned?

Tags: scams

I once saw a travel show on Discovery or Nat Geo, I can't remember which one, in which the host of the show travels to different cities around the world and exposes how travelers are conned.

Just wanted to know the name of the show so that I can prep up ahead of my visit.

Comment: Can you edit the word "conned" out of the question title and text? The one I find in the dictionary seems to be the wrong one (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conned), so many non-native speakers have a hard time understanding what it is about (as you don't give any hints on what it could mean in the text).

Comment: @DCTLib [link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conned) Check out #4.

Comment: @CaptainBlack #4 is a noun.

Comment: @DCTLib He meant #4 in the link he gave; or #6 in M-W. Either case, I am a non-native speaker and had no trouble in understanding what the OP meant (if he meant swindled!).

Comment: I have not seen the show you're referring to, but I can recommend [this book](http://amzn.to/14F4xMG), which is likely to be more valuable than a TV show, as it can naturally go into much greater detail, and is less likely to be susceptible to sensationalism.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The third result to https://google.com/search?q=travel+show+exposing+cons is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scam_City

> Scam City is a television show which started airing on Travel + Escape in June 2012, and has subsequently aired on the National Geographic Channel and in Australia on the subscription channel Nat Geo People. Host Conor Woodman travels to some of the world's most popular cities in an effort to expose the darker side of tourism.

Edit: of course, this is television. They will focus on the criminals in a city where millions of honest, everyday people live. While being aware of some scams is not a bad idea, having bad expectations based on this show is not warranted. Not to mention at least the Prague episode was staged with hired actors. Check articles like [Common scams](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Common_scams) or [40 tourist scams to avoid](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travelnews/10980488/40-tourist-scams-to-avoid.html) instead to be prepared.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning there's some controversy over how genuine the show is (as mentioned on the page you link). If someone is researching prior to travel I could see the show causing a level of anxiety that's not really warranted.

Comment: @SpaceDog added.

Comment: Heh, we got overcharged in Prague by a taxi of the company recommended by all guidebooks leaving from one of their official ranks. (Long way round drive.)

Comment: the Amsterdam episode reportedly was also staged. Which doesn't mean similar scams don't happen, but not to the extent or in the manners portrayed (which makes sense, it's both easier and far less dangerous staging things than trying to actually get conned).